# Footer gives different results on Code Snippet (CodePen) and Angular

Tags: html, css, angular, flexbox, footer

So I wanted my footer to cover the entire length of the page and stick to the bottom of the page, getting pushed down if some content gets added, what happened is, on codepen everything works perfectly, on Angular (14), it does not cover the length of the page, instead, it leaves some space on the left, right and bottom and I don't know why I will attach the code

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@300;400;500;600;700&display=swap');

body {
    /* fonto e grandezza font*/
    line-height: 1;
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
}

* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

/* tiene il footer esteso evitando gli spazi sui lati */
html,
body {
    height: 100%;
}

body {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.content {
    /*   flex: 1 0 auto; */
    flex-direction: column;
}

.footer {
    flex-shrink: 0;
}

.container {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;

}

.row {
    /*si occupa delle righe, accomoda lo spostamento dell'elenco con il dimensionamento della pagina */
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

ul {
    list-style: none;
}

.footer {
    /* solamente il colore di background del footer e lo spazio tra gli elementi */
    background-color: #24262b;
    padding: 20px 0;
}

.footer-col {
    /* si occupa delle colonne e del loro ridimensionamento */
    width: 25%;
    padding: 0;
}

.footer-col h4 {
    /*stabilisco la grandezza del font e del colore dei titoli */
    font-size: 25px;
    color: #ffffff;
    text-transform: capitalize;
    margin-bottom: 35px;
    font-weight: 500;
    position: relative;
}

.footer-col h4::before {
    /* barra rossa sotto ai titoli */
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    bottom: -10px;
    background-color: #e91e63;
    height: 2px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 50px;
}

.footer-col ul li:not(:last-child) {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    /* spazio tra le scritte in verticale */
}

.footer-col ul li a {
    /* stato degli elementi dell'elenco pre-hover, potete notare che dispongo qui "transition" cioè il tempo che ci metterà a passare allo stato dell'hover dal suo stato normale e viceversa */
    font-size: 16px;
    text-transform: capitalize;
    color: #ffffff;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: 300;
    color: #bbbbbb;
    display: block;
    transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

.footer-col ul li a:hover {
    /* colore e leggero spostamento quando avviene l'hover (cioè quando ci passa sopra il mouse) */
    color: #ffffff;
    padding-left: 8px;
}

.footer-col .social-links a {
    /* stesso meccaniscmo dei font, qui però inserisco il background-color per il cambiamento del color  (color -> background-color)*/
    display: inline-block;
    height: 40px;
    width: 40px;
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
    margin: 0 10px 10px 0;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 40px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    color: #ffffff;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

.footer-col .social-links a:hover {
    color: #24262b;
    background-color: #ffffff;
}

.content {

    display: block;
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 15px auto;
    text-align: center;
    font: 25px Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    width: 300px;
    display: flex;

}

.foot {
    display: inline;
    line-height: 70px;
}

/* dove si trova il logo, lo inizializzo con un filtro grigio e una transizione di 0.6, uso webkit per la scala di grigio (e anche la transizione solo per webkit), la scala di grigio viene usata perché rende il contrasto con l'hover molto più bello */
.content img {
    height: 150px;
    width: 150px;
    float: left;
    filter: grayscale(100%);
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);
    -webkit-transition: all .6s ease-in-out;
    transition: 0.6s;
}

/* hover del logo */
.content img:hover {
    filter: invert(400%);
    filter: brightness(4);
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(-100);
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.10);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/src/app/footer/footer.component.css">
    <!--import css footer-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.1/css/all.min.css">
</head>

<body>
    <!--parte footer dell'html-->
    <!--parte footer dell'html-->
    <div class="content">
        <div>
            <h1>Heelo</h1>
            <h1>Heelo</h1>
            <h1>Heelo</h1>
            <h1>Heelo</h1>
            <h1>Heelo</h1>
        </div>
        <div>
            <h1>Heelo</h1>
            <h1>Heelo</h1>
            <h1>Heelo</h1>
            <h1>Heelo</h1>
            <h1>Heelo</h1>
        </div>
        <div>
            <h1>Heelo</h1>
            <h1>Heelo</h1>
            <h1>Heelo</h1>
            <h1>Heelo</h1>
            <h1>Heelo</h1>
        </div>
        <div>
            <h1>Heelo</h1>
            <h1>Heelo</h1>
            <h1>Heelo</h1>
            <h1>Heelo</h1>
            <h1>Heelo</h1>
        </div>
    </div>

    <footer class="footer">
        <div class="flex-wrapper">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="footer-col">
                        <div class="content">
                            <a href="#">
                                <!--i link da collegare vanno dove sono presenti gli #-->
                                <img src="https://i.imgur.com/1yvwx9I.png">
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="footer-col">
                        <h4>Azienda</h4>
                        <!--titolo-->
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="chi-siamo">Chi Siamo</a></li>
                            <!--elenco degli elementi-->
                            <li><a href="contatti">Contattaci</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Placeholder</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">PlaceHolder</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <div class="footer-col">
                        <h4>Aiuto</h4>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="faq">FAQ</a></li>
                            <li><a href="consegne">Consegne</a></li>
                            <li><a href="reso">Reso</a></li>
                            <li><a href="privacy">Informatica privacy</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <div class="footer-col">
                        <h4>Seguici su</h4>
                        <div class="social-links">
                            <a href="facebook"><i class="fab fa-facebook-f"></i></a>
                            <!--icone dei social-->
                            <a href="twitter"><i class="fab fa-twitter"></i></a>
                            <a href="instagram"><i class="fab fa-instagram"></i></a>
                            <a href="linkedin"><i class="fab fa-linkedin-in"></i></a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </footer>

</body>

</html>
```

and the image of the problem (please don't mind the random text, it was for testing)

[image: problem]

OH! And also I tried setting right left and bottom at 0 but to no avail.

Comment: I am unsure whether your code snippet presented on this question is working as you expected or not. Can you please provide the link to the codepen? Even better, if you could somehow share the angular snippet running in the angular environment.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't exactly get what problem you are facing based on the current version of your question. However, I assume that it is regarding space below your footer and content when you have less content.

Since, you are making the body of the html a flex, you can simply add a justification to accommodate a space in between content and footer by:

```
body {
  ...
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

If you are concerned about the space on left and right, may be there is some margin defined somewhere which I cannot see on this snippet.

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@300;400;500;600;700&display=swap');
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  /* fonto e grandezza font*/
  line-height: 1;
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
}


/* tiene il footer esteso evitando gli spazi sui lati */

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

.content {
  /*   flex: 1 0 auto; */
  flex-direction: column;
}

.footer {
  flex-shrink: 0;
}

.container {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.row {
  /*si occupa delle righe, accomoda lo spostamento dell'elenco con il dimensionamento della pagina */
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
}

.footer {
  /* solamente il colore di background del footer e lo spazio tra gli elementi */
  background-color: #24262b;
  padding: 20px 0;
}

.footer-col {
  /* si occupa delle colonne e del loro ridimensionamento */
  width: 25%;
  padding: 0;
}

.footer-col h4 {
  /*stabilisco la grandezza del font e del colore dei titoli */
  font-size: 25px;
  color: #ffffff;
  text-transform: capitalize;
  margin-bottom: 35px;
  font-weight: 500;
  position: relative;
}

.footer-col h4::before {
  /* barra rossa sotto ai titoli */
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: -10px;
  background-color: #e91e63;
  height: 2px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 50px;
}

.footer-col ul li:not(:last-child) {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  /* spazio tra le scritte in verticale */
}

.footer-col ul li a {
  /* stato degli elementi dell'elenco pre-hover, potete notare che dispongo qui "transition" cioè il tempo che ci metterà a passare allo stato dell'hover dal suo stato normale e viceversa */
  font-size: 16px;
  text-transform: capitalize;
  color: #ffffff;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: 300;
  color: #bbbbbb;
  display: block;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

.footer-col ul li a:hover {
  /* colore e leggero spostamento quando avviene l'hover (cioè quando ci passa sopra il mouse) */
  color: #ffffff;
  padding-left: 8px;
}

.footer-col .social-links a {
  /* stesso meccaniscmo dei font, qui però inserisco il background-color per il cambiamento del color  (color -> background-color)*/
  display: inline-block;
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
  margin: 0 10px 10px 0;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 40px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  color: #ffffff;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

.footer-col .social-links a:hover {
  color: #24262b;
  background-color: #ffffff;
}

.content {
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 15px auto;
  text-align: center;
  font: 25px Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  width: 300px;
  display: flex;
}


/* dove si trova il logo, lo inizializzo con un filtro grigio e una transizione di 0.6, uso webkit per la scala di grigio (e anche la transizione solo per webkit), la scala di grigio viene usata perché rende il contrasto con l'hover molto più bello */

.content img {
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
  float: left;
  filter: grayscale(100%);
  -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);
  -webkit-transition: all .6s ease-in-out;
  transition: 0.6s;
}


/* hover del logo */

.content img:hover {
  filter: invert(400%);
  filter: brightness(4);
  -webkit-filter: grayscale(-100);
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.10);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/src/app/footer/footer.component.css">
  <!--import css footer-->
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.1/css/all.min.css">
</head>

<body>
  <!--parte footer dell'html-->
  <!--parte footer dell'html-->
  <div class="content">
    <div>
      <h1>Heelo</h1>
      <h1>Heelo</h1>
      <h1>Heelo</h1>
      <h1>Heelo</h1>
      <h1>Heelo</h1>
    </div>
    <div>
      <h1>Heelo</h1>
      <h1>Heelo</h1>
      <h1>Heelo</h1>
      <h1>Heelo</h1>
      <h1>Heelo</h1>
    </div>
    <div>
      <h1>Heelo</h1>
      <h1>Heelo</h1>
      <h1>Heelo</h1>
      <h1>Heelo</h1>
      <h1>Heelo</h1>
    </div>
    <div>
      <h1>Heelo</h1>
      <h1>Heelo</h1>
      <h1>Heelo</h1>
      <h1>Heelo</h1>
      <h1>Heelo</h1>
    </div>
  </div>

  <footer class="footer">
    <div class="flex-wrapper">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="footer-col">
            <div class="content">
              <a href="#">
                <!--i link da collegare vanno dove sono presenti gli #-->
                <img src="https://i.imgur.com/1yvwx9I.png">
              </a>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="footer-col">
            <h4>Azienda</h4>
            <!--titolo-->
            <ul>
              <li><a href="chi-siamo">Chi Siamo</a></li>
              <!--elenco degli elementi-->
              <li><a href="contatti">Contattaci</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Placeholder</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">PlaceHolder</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <div class="footer-col">
            <h4>Aiuto</h4>
            <ul>
              <li><a href="faq">FAQ</a></li>
              <li><a href="consegne">Consegne</a></li>
              <li><a href="reso">Reso</a></li>
              <li><a href="privacy">Informatica privacy</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <div class="footer-col">
            <h4>Seguici su</h4>
            <div class="social-links">
              <a href="facebook"><i class="fab fa-facebook-f"></i></a>
              <!--icone dei social-->
              <a href="twitter"><i class="fab fa-twitter"></i></a>
              <a href="instagram"><i class="fab fa-instagram"></i></a>
              <a href="linkedin"><i class="fab fa-linkedin-in"></i></a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </footer>

</body>

</html>
```